Nav closes when expanding dropdown on mobile
Hi smart people I hope you can help.
If I open my nav on mobile it works fine. However when I expand the inner dropdown the nav automatically closes and I need to reopen the nav. I feel I am missing something basic and hope that someone can assist on this.
What I would like to have is that the nav stays open when a user expands the inner dropdown menu


/* Navigation bar style */

.nav {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs {
  list-style: none !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Nunito Sans !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

.nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: white !important;
}

.nav .nav-item .nav-link.active {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
}

.nav .nav-item a.nav-link.active:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.nav .nav-item a.nav-link:focus,
.nav .nav-item a.nav-link:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.nav .nav-item a.nav-link.active:focus {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background: #141414 !important;
  border: 1px solid #00fff2 !important;
  font-family: Nunito Sans !important;
  margin-top: 30px !important;
  display: none;
  /* Initially hide all dropdown menus */
}


/* Show dropdown menu when parent link is focused */

.dropdown-toggle:focus+.dropdown-item,
.dropdown-toggle:hover+.dropdown-item {
  display: block !important;
}


/* Additional CSS for keeping dropdown menu open on mobile when focused */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-item,
  .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-item a:focus,
  .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-item a:hover {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.dropdown-item {
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0em 0.1em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: white !important;
  padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}

.dropdown-item i {
  display: none !important;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.dropdown-item a:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.et-menu a:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li a:hover {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #00fff2 !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  text-shadow: 0em 0.1em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.nav-content nav.navbar .navbar-nav>.active>a,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #00fff2;
}

.nav-content nav.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: theme_navigation_text_color;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu>a {
    color: #00fff2 !important;
  }
  nav.navbar .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu>a:hover,
  nav.navbar .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu>a:focus {
    color: #00fff2 !important;
  }
}

.nav-content nav.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #00fff2 !important;
}

.nav-content nav.navbar .navbar-nav>.open>a,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #00fff2 !important;
}
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_menu et_pb_menu_0_tb_header et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left et_dropdown_animation_fade et_pb_menu--without-logo et_pb_menu--style-centered">




  <div class="et_pb_menu_inner_container clearfix">

    <div class="et_pb_menu__wrap">
      <div class="et_pb_menu__menu">
        <nav class="et-menu-nav">
          <ul id="menu-mainmenu" class="et-menu nav">
            <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-1104"><a href="https://www.hosting.webadventures.co.za/">Home</a></li>


            <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home" class="nav-item active dropdown">
              <a href="/acc/client/" class="nav-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class=""></i> Dashboard </a>


              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/acc/client/services/index/"><i
                                        class=""></i>
                                    Services</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/acc/plugin/domains/client_main/index/"><i
                                        class=""></i>
                                    Domains</a>
              </div>

            </li>


            <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home" class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a href="/acc/plugin/support_manager/client_main/" class="nav-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class=""></i> Support </a>


              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/acc/plugin/support_manager/client_tickets/"><i
                                        class=""></i>
                                    Tickets</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/acc/plugin/support_manager/knowledgebase/"><i
                                        class=""></i>
                                    Knowledge Base</a>
              </div>

            </li>


            <li class="nav-item dropdown et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Frana Test                                    <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/acc/client/main/edit/"><i
                                        class="fas fa-edit fa-fw"></i>
                                Manage Account</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/acc/client/emails/"><i
                                    class="fas fa-inbox fa-fw"></i>
                                Email History</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/acc/"><i
                                    class="far fa-circle fa-fw"></i>
                                Return to Portal</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/acc/client/logout/"><i
                                    class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i>
                                Log Out</a>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </nav>
      </div>


      <div class="et_mobile_nav_menu">
        <div class="mobile_nav closed">
          <span class="mobile_menu_bar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>




Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Besides being as minimal as possible the example you provided most importantly needs to be reproducible. For the shown code, there is nothing that would make the elements with the class dropdown-menu (which are initially not visible) visible.
